# Query in Shiny R to retrieve the data from the database using reactive input

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

```
**UI.R**

library(shiny)

shinyUI
  (fluidPage
    (
      titlePanel("Predict"),

      sidebarLayout
      (
        sidebarPanel
          (
            (numericInput("tenth", label = h3("X Percentage"), value = 90)) ),
        mainPanel("Main Panel")
      )
    )
)


**Server.R**

library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)


shinyServer(
  function(input,output)
  {
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "rstudio", host = "localhost", 
                    port = 3306, user = "root", password = "")

    query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM userdetails where SSC = %s",input$tenth)
  }
)
```

**The error**
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I know that I need to add the database query in a reactive expression or isolate. But how do i write that. I need to show the data retrieved to the user and even use the data for further computation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a `get_data()` reactive in `server.R` inside of the `function(input, output)` stuff.

```
get_data <- reactive({
  query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM userdetails where SSC = %s",input$tenth)
  df <- dbSendQuery(conn, query)
  return(df)
})
```

Then access that data using `get_data()` later on...